# jQuery-Mobile pagecontainerbeforechange does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm working on a single-page-application. I need the `pagecontainerbeforechange` event from jQuery-Mobile because i want to check if my site-wrapper has the class "`show-nav`". When the site-wrapper has this class, the site-menu is opened up and the content moves 350px to the left. So if the user now clicks on register, and before he has the site-menu opened up, my register page is moved away and there is no possiblity to get it back because there is no site-menu on the registerpage.

First i tried to use the `pagecontainerload` event till i saw that it is deprecated. Then i changed it to the `pagecontainerloadbeforechange` event but i cant get it work.

The page i want to check for the class "`.show-nav`" has the id #registration

So, the user is on the main site, he clicks on "register" and before the page changes the class "`.show-nav`" should be removed. The function for removing the class is already set up, but i don't know how to call it the right way.

```
    function toggleNav() {
        if ($('.site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')) {
            // Do things on Nav Close
            $('.site-wrapper').removeClass('show-nav');
        }
```

**More detailed Description ->**

While i wrote this detailed Description i got the solution and it is so simple that it is embarrassing for me: Removed the site-wrapper from the site #registration...thats all.

Thanks for your help and thanks for you edit omar!

Comment: `pagecontainerload` isn't deprecated and `pagecontainerbeforechange` should fire. Add your complete code pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add toggleClass to .site-wrapper. If it has the class .show-nav it will remove it, otherwise it will add the class :)

```
$('.site-wrapper').toggleClass('show-nav');
```

Comment: It should remove it everytime it has the class. It should never add the class on that side because then the registration formular is moved away like you can see on the screenshot :-/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Think that is not possible, but i'm going to edit my posting above with more screenshots and a more detailed description. Give me 10 Min

Answer (score 0):

*pagecontainerbeforechange* is part of **Pagecontainer Widget**.

At this moment (jqm 1.4.x) this widget is designed as a singlton, binded to body element. So if you want to detect page change you should use the code above:

```
$( "body" ).on( "pagecontainerbeforechange", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(ui);
} );
```